# Consuming Powershell stdout with events occurs out-of-order

Tags: powershell

Given a batch script like

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (0, 1, 1000) do echo %%x
```

I'm attempting to run it and capture output to return stdout and stderr over WinRM. The full example is at https://github.com/puppetlabs/bolt/blob/master/lib/bolt/transport/winrm/connection.rb#L112.

The short version is

```
function Invoke-Interpreter
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
  [Parameter()]
  [String]
  $Path
)

  $startInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo($Path)
  $startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
  $startInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
  $startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true

  $stdoutHandler = { if (-not ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($EventArgs.Data))) { $Host.UI.WriteLine($EventArgs.Data) } }

  $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
  $process.StartInfo = $startInfo
  $process.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

  $stdoutEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $process -EventName 'OutputDataReceived' -Action $stdoutHandler

  [Void] $process.Start()

  $process.BeginOutputReadLine()

  $ret = $process.WaitForExit()
  Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $stdoutEvent.Name

  exit $process.ExitCode
}

Invoke-Interpreter './foo.bat'
```

When run directly in Powershell (I put it in a .ps1 script and repeatedly invoked it), I occasionally get lines printed out-of-order. An example is

```
...
970
971
972
973
974
975
976
977
978
979
980
981
982
983
984
985
986
987
988
989
990
991
992
993
994
995
996
997
998
999
1000
778
```

Any thoughts on what's going wrong? I've reproduced this in Windows Server 2012, Windows 10 Enterprise, and Nano Server.

Comment: Why are you doing all that extra work?

Comment: It's an interesting symptom, but let's take a step back:
What @TheIncorrigible1 is trying to say in his comment: your entire function can be replaced with this single invocation:  `& './foo.bat'` - it executes the batch file synchronously and output its stdout output as an array of lines.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a3786158ca51cd65388743f900b69ec9e253c3d9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/EventManager.cs#L972-L976) PowerShell schedule event processing in `ThreadPool`. Since thread pool does not guaranty order in which work items will be processed, you are not receive any guaranty about order in which event will be processed.

Comment: Thanks PetSerAI, I thought that might be the case but couldn't find anything talking about it.

Comment: I think the primary reason for all the extra work was to have a timeout on the script being run. Definitely re-evaluating whether that's needed.